# Show that $H_c = (cI - H)(I-\bar{c}H)^{-1}$ is unitary if H is unitary.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

I'm struggling with the following question.

> Let H be a Unitary matrix and define $H_c = (cI - H)(I-\bar{c}H)^{-1}$ for $c \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $H_c$ is also unitary.

Using properties of the conjugate transpose we have that $$H_c^* H_c = (I - cH^*)^{-1}(\bar{c}I - H^*)(cI - H)(I - \bar{c}H)^{-1}.$$ But I don't see how to progress. The fact that polynomials of $H$ commutes might be useful. Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: If you swap  the order of the middle terms, you willget: $H_c^* H_c=-(\bar{c}I - H)(I - \bar{c}H)^{-1}.$

Comment: You are not writing $H_c^{*}$ correctly. $H$ is not self adjoint.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes that is true. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Fred I agree with that but I don't see your point.

Comment: If you can't prove this, replace $H$ by a complex number $z$ of modulus $1$ everywhere and show that $\overline z_c z_c=1$. Then see what happens if you try to do the same computations for $H$ instead of $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $H$ is unitary twice to get
\begin{align*}
(\bar c I-H^\ast)(cI-H) &=(\bar c HH^\ast-H^\ast)(cHH^\ast-H)\\
&=(\bar cH-I) H^\ast H (cH^\ast-I)\\
&=(\bar cH-I) (cH^\ast-I)\\
\end{align*}
Now since $H$, $H^\ast$ and $I$ all commute with each other, we can commute the above to get
\begin{align*}
H_c^\ast H_c &= (I-cH^\ast)^{-1}(\bar c I-H^\ast)(cI-H)(I-\bar cH)^{-1}\\
&= (I-cH^\ast)^{-1}(\bar cH-I) (cH^\ast-I)(I-\bar cH)^{-1}\\
&= (I-cH^\ast)^{-1}(cH^\ast-I)(\bar cH-I)(I-\bar cH)^{-1}\\
&=I
\end{align*}
The proof for $H_cH_c^\ast$ is almost identical.